# Invoke-AzureRmHDInsightHiveJob : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: azure, azure-storage, hadoop2, azure-powershell, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to run a Hive query using powershell against my HDInsight cluster. The Hadoop job completes successfully as i can see the logs in the yarn UI. But the `Invoke-AzureRmHDInsightHiveJob` command fails with the below error. What i doing wrong?

[image]

This is the complete code :

```
$RunAsConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection;

try 
{
    $Login=Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $RunAsConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $RunAsConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $RunAsConnection.CertificateThumbprint -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Sleep 10;
    $Login=Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $RunAsConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $RunAsConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $RunAsConnection.CertificateThumbprint
};

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $RunAsConnection.SubscriptionID

Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $RunAsConnection.TenantID -ApplicationId $RunAsConnection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $RunAsConnection.CertificateThumbprint

$ResourceGroupName = "xxxxxx"
$StorageAccountName = "xxxxxx"
$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Value[0]
$StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$StorageAccountContainer = "xxxxxx"

$clusterName = "xxxxxx"
$creds=Get-Credential -Message "Enter the login for the cluster"

Use-AzureRmHDInsightCluster -ClusterName $clusterName -HttpCredential $creds

$queryString = "select 1"

Invoke-AzureRmHDInsightHiveJob -Query $queryString -Verbose -DefaultStorageAccountName "$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net" -DefaultStorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey -DefaultContainer $StorageAccountContainer
```

Comment: Similar issue has already been addressed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7dbc5bfa-f2b9-4ae0-8184-a34cd9bf5ee9/hive-execution-issue-from-azure-power-shell?forum=hdinsight see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ashok. I doubt that it is a timeout issue. I tested with "select 1", which shouldn't take more than a few seconds.